# Android Studio: refuse gradle to download dependencies which has been downloaded

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I don't have access to internet all the time. I use dependencies to add libraries to my project when I am online. for example for using cards library I add this to build.gradle:

`compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'`

so it goes online and download the related files.

Now I'm offline and don't have access to INTERNET. I started another project and want to use that cards library again, But it says:

`Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0`

**Why it try to download the library again while I have it on my system?** How Can I use this dependency in other project in offline mode?

**I don't want to copy .jar file to my project I want to use the downloaded file by declare it in dependencies.**

Comment: Are you sure that answer is for Android Studio?!

Comment: Where is that settings file in Android studio?

Comment: Do you have any dependencies with a version that includes a `+`, like so: `com.example:library:1.+`

Comment: No, as I said I write `'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'`

Comment: Yes, but do you use the `+` in any other dependencies in your project?

Comment: No Sir! `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
    `androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`
    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`
    `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'`
    `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'`
    `compile project(':ResideMenu')`
    `compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.1.0'`
    `compile 'co.ronash.pushe:android-lib:0.9.1'`
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`
   ` compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

You can set Android Studio to offline mode in the settings: `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Offline work`

Comment: I did that sir, But for new dependency it try to go online so says that "disable offline work". I can't go online every time!